# Betting Combinations and Permutations

Tags: permutations, combinations

I was thinking about betting and it appeared to me. It is possible to win 270 million in my currency from placing a multi-bet.  But you have to get all of them correct. Now, you could place win for one team, draw or win for the other team. Now, there are 17 different matches to choose from. If I were to place a bet on all possible outcomes of these matches, how would I calculate how many ways they are?

Comment: $2^{17}=131072$

Answer (score 1):

Let's define a string or characters, for example "$121$" which says that for the first match team 1 wins, then for the second match team 2 wins (or draw), and then for the third match team 1 wins.

Hence we are looking for the number of string made of $17$ characters in the set $\{"1", "2"\}$. There are exactly $2^{17} = 131072$ possible combinations.

---

Actually I assumed that there are exactly two possible outcomes for one match, "win team 1" or "win team 2 or draw". Maybe you wanted to mean "win for team 1", "draw", "win for team 2". In this case we have $3$ outcome per match. Hence a total of $3^{17} = 129140163$ possibilites.

Comment: Thanks. I now see those are way too many bets.

Comment: @user104474 If you like this answer you should accept it (the check mark) and upvote it (the up arrow).